# Resizing a FAT-based filesystem

Tags: filesystems, fat32, exfat, fat16, vfat

Is it possible to grow or shrink a FAT filesystem like it is possible to resize ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems? I am NOT talking about resizing partitions.

Answer (score 3):

No. A file systems is what *fills* a partition, so if you don't want to grow the partition, there is nowhere to grow the file system to. So no, it is not possible, independent of the file system type. You can only grow the partition and the file system inside with it.